# Generalised Fourier Transform for Spherical Bessel Functions

Tags: partial-differential-equations, fourier-transform, bessel-functions

I'm trying to find to solve the following PDE:

$$\nabla ^2\phi(\vec{x}) +k^2 \phi(\vec{x})=0$$

In spherical coordinates and then use the Generalised Fourier Transform to extract 2 linearly independent solutions.

Using separation of variables, I have:
$$\frac{d^2R}{dr^2} + \frac{2}{r}\frac{dR}{dr}-\frac{l(l+1)}{r^2}R + k^2R=0$$

Then using the transformations: $R=r^lX$ and $x=kr$, I end up with:
$$\frac{d^2X}{dx^2} + \frac{2(1+l)}{x}\frac{dX}{dx} + X=0$$

At this point, I introduce the generalised fourier transform: $X(x) = \int_C e^{zx}\tilde{X}(z)dz$.

$$\int_C dz \tilde{X}(z)[2z(1+l) +(z^2+1)x]e^{zx}= 0$$

Now I need (apparently) to get rid of $x$ by stating that $x=\frac{d}{dz}e^{zx}$, therefore:
$$\int_C dz \tilde{X}(z)[2z(1+l) +(z^2+1)\frac{d}{dz}]e^{zx}=0$$

Developing the integrals for the sum and using integration by parts:

$$[\tilde{X}(z)(z^2+1)e^{zx}] + \int_C dz e^{zx}[2z(1+l) - \frac{d}{dz}(z^2+1)]\tilde{X}(z) = 0$$

I need to make the integral term vanish:

$$\frac{d}{dz}\tilde{X}(z)(z^2+1)=2z(1+l)\tilde{X}(z)$$
$$\frac{1}{\tilde{X}(z)(z^2+1)}\frac{d}{dz}\tilde{X}(z)(z^2+1)=\frac{2z(1+l)}{z^2+1}$$
$$\tilde{X}(z) = (z^2+1)^l$$

This is where I am stuck. I need to determine the analytical structure of $\tilde{X}(z)$ and then determine what contour to use for the boundary term to be $0$. Then actually find $X(x)$.

From what I understand, the Riemann structure of $\tilde{X}(z)$ has zeros at $+i$ and $-i$ and when have a corkscrew type formation. Do we have one at each zeros ?

Then because of the $e^{zx}$ in the boundary term, our contour extends to $\Re (z)<0$ since $x>0$ as it is a radial component in this problem.

Other than that I don't have any other ideas. Any help?

Many thanks!

Comment: $$X(x)=\mathcal{F}_z^{-1}\left[\left(z^2+1\right)^l\right](x)=\frac{2^{l+1} | x| ^{-l-\frac{1}{2}} K_{l+\frac{1}{2}}(| x| )}{\Gamma (-l)}$$

doesn't satisfy

$$\frac{d^2X}{dx^2} + \frac{2(1+l)}{x}\frac{dX}{dx} + X=0$$

Comment: @gpmath would you happen to know where I went wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Why you don't use the general solution

$$X(x)\to x^{-l-\frac{1}{2}} \left(c_1 J_{l+\frac{1}{2}}(x)+c_2 Y_{l+\frac{1}{2}}(x)\right)$$

If you absolutely need an integral transformation, then use Laplace, see [Laplace transform for nonlinear ODE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2115669/laplace-transform-non-linear-ode).

$$\mathcal{L}_x\left[2 (l+1) X'(x)+x X''(x)+x X(x)\right](z)=2 l z \tilde{X}(z)-\left(z^2+1\right) \tilde{X}'(z)-((2 l+1) X(0))$$

Solution of this ODE is $\tilde{X}(z)\to -(2 l+1) X(0) z \left(z^2+1\right)^l \, _2F_1\left(\frac{1}{2},l+1;\frac{3}{2};-z^2\right)+c_1 \left(z^2+1\right)^l$

With the assumption $X(0)=0$
$$X(x)=\mathcal{L}_z^{-1}\left[\tilde{X}(z)\text{/.}\, X(0)\to 0\right](x)=\frac{\sqrt{\pi } c_1 2^{l+\frac{1}{2}} x^{-l-\frac{1}{2}} J_{-l-\frac{1}{2}}(x)}{\Gamma (-l)}$$

you get the BesselJ(x) function of the first kind which is one part of the general solution for $X(0)=0$.

Comment: I'm trying to work out an example seen in class that has not a lot of details. I need to use the generalised fourier transform and determine an appropriate contour. Maybe it's not the best way to do it but this is how we did it and I'm trying to understand the reasoning behind it.